# Como puedo incluir archivos js externos en ionic 3

Tags: ionic3

estoy trabajando con ionic 3 e intento trabajar con archivos js...
He seguido otro post donde me piden agregar algunas cosas en index.html y app.component.ts (y lo he hecho) pero al querer mostrar en consola lo que contiene la variable declarada en el js me marca como undefined, pero se supone que ya llame al archivo js en las páginas anteriores... alguien me podría decir porque no me funciona??

Comment: Muestranos el codigo de como lo integraste.

Comment: ya :DDDDDDDDDDDD

Comment: Alguien que me ayudeee! :(

Answer (score 1):

Este es el código

test.js

```
var testvar = "Hola mundo en js y llamado desde ionic 3";
```

index.html

```
<!-- cordova.js required for cordova apps (remove if not needed) -->
  <script src="cordova.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/test.js"></script>
```

app.component.ts

```
import * as test from '../assets/js/test';
declare var testvar;
console.log(test.testvar);//Aqui mando a mostrar el mensaje (undefined)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
`>archivo hola.js
>---------------ini
>alert("hola");

>chau(); 

>function chau(){
>//alert("chau");
>console.log("Hola mundo en js y llamado desde ionic 3");
>    
>};
>-------------------------fin
>
>en el home.page.ts /o donde usarlo
>----------inicio
>import * as test from '../../assets/js/hola'; /
>
>---------fin
>
>
>en el constructor o donde quieras pero que este donde esta el import * as test
>--------------inicio
> test.chau();introducir el código aquí
>
>-------------fin`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<pre>
archivo Fu.js
---------------ini
alert("hola");
chau(); 
function chau(){
//alert("chau");
console.log("Hola mundo en js y llamado desde ionic 3");
};
-------------------------fin
en el home.page.ts /o donde usarlo
----------inicio
import * as Fu from '../../assets/js/Fu';
---------fin
en el constructor o donde quieras pero que este donde esta el import * as Fu
--------------inicio
Fu.bienvenido
-------------fin`
</pre>
```